# What Alt+f4 actually does? Will using it frequently cause any harm to the system?

Tags: windows, windows-7, gaming

The very first thing I notice when using this method to quickly close a running program/game is potential **data loss**, like settings. But if I'm perfectly OK with that, will keeping doing this cause any **long-term** harm to the system, either software or hardware like RAM?

Also, I'd like to know what Alt+f4 **actually does**? If it actually tries to kill the associated process, it would take no time for the program/game to close, but as I noticed, some games (and most of them) freeze for some seconds before actually closing, while if I kill their processes in Task manager, they will close almost immediately.

One more thing I know is many games and programs seem to have been implemented with this as a hotkey for quick-exit, so they will actually ask if I want to quit and save the progress before quitting, just like normal procedure.

Comment: The shortcut just exists the process. Any loss of data would be isolated to the current data loaded by the process your teling Windows to exit. Furthermore the behavior of this exist procedure is left up to the application itself.  A program can even block this shortcut if it so desires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt-F4 is the windows command to close an application.

The application itself has the ability to execute code when ALT-F4 is pressed.

You should know that alt-f4 will never terminate an application while being in a read/write sequence unless the application itself knows it is safe to abort.

When talking about games, developers often do not keep in mind that people press the ALT-F4 to quickly exit a game. If the game is saving at that moment (often seen by an indicator of some sorts with a message: do not power off the computer if you see this indicator) and you press ALT-F4, the chances are high that the profile will become corrupt and your savegame is lost.

As for implementation, it works the other way around. Since this is a windows shortcut key, unless a program/game explicitly prevent ALT-F4 to not exit its program, it will always work.

Comment: "You should know that alt-f4 will never terminate an application while being in a read/write sequence unless the application itself knows it is safe to abort."
What about Alt+F4 in-between read/write operations.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Alt-F4 is only a call to the app's shutdown function. if its not aborted, it means the app knows its save to abort. Otherwise it will wait with the shutdown and queue it to the end of the operations. If the app is poorly written, you will corrupt files.

Comment: That's my point, and why it should be clear that it's up to the developers (so what bothered me about your statement is the word "never"). I wouldn't generally trust a program to know when it's done writing or going to write some more, because what's for sure is that naive applications would corrupt.

Comment: @MasterMastic: I haven't ever found an application where this could be a problem. Games is a different story though, but if you talk about known apps or apps in alpha, yes, then ALT-F4 may be like this.

Comment: This answer is technically incorrect.  The correct answer is PoutchiPatch's answer.  Alt-F4 simply sends the SIGINT signal to the program.  The program doesnt actually have to to honor the signal, it can be changed to ignore it, or do something else.  As for saving, unless the developer is very bad, the program will not exit until all processes are finished - hence why some programs dont respond to Alt-F4 when an in program process is stuck.

Answer (score 11):

alt+f4 is a built-in OS shortcut which, when triggered, will send a SIGINT signal to the process managing the active window. SIGINT (as for signal interrupt) is a signal meant to tell the process that is has been requested to stop. When developing an application, you can define in it's behavior that it can "catch" a signal, meaning that you modify the course of action automatically defined by the application when it receives such signal.

A good example of this would be a text editor. Any application receiving a SIGINT will exit, however, developers of text editors will preferably override this behavior to ask the user if it wants to save the current opened file before exiting. In that case developers tell the program not to exit when receiving the SIGINT, but instead prompting the user, and depending on the user choice, manually exit (for example, in Microsoft Word, if the user chooses cancel, the program won't exit, even if it received a SIGINT).

There are several signals with different uses, and there even are several signals regarding exiting an application. Theoritically, you can choose the behavior you want for any of these. SIGINT, for example, could be considered a "soft" exit signal. SIGKILL, on the other hand, is the hardest exit signal that exists, and should never be overriden, as if it is sent, it is usually because the user wants immediate interruption of the program, no questions asked. I could bet, for example, that if you sent a SIGKILL to Microsoft Word, it would exit immediately, even if you have unsaved changes.

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect.  This is the correct answer.